# Reshape categorical data that looks like a correlation matrix

Tags: r, matrix, reshape, r-corrplot

I have a df:

```
cc pair_no
US   1
US   1
DE   2
UK   2
US   3
PL   3
US   4
US   4
```

I would like to  create a matrix as such, basically to count the number of pairs per country combination:

```
    US  UK  PL DE
US  2
UK  0   0   
PL  1   0    0
DE  0   1    0   0
```

I have tried using but it does not give the desired results.

```
Table(df$cc,df$pair_no)
```

Can anybody help?

Comment: by pairs you mean countries in rows ( i , i + 1) ?

Comment: @DiegoAgher pairs are the ones with the same pair number

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

```
table(data.frame(cc1=df$cc[c(TRUE,FALSE)],cc2=df$cc[c(FALSE,TRUE)]))
#    cc2
#cc1  DE PL UK US
#  DE  0  0  1  0
#  PL  0  0  0  0
#  UK  0  0  0  0
#  US  0  1  0  2
```

**Data**

```
df<-structure(list(cc = structure(c(4L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 4L
), .Label = c("DE", "PL", "UK", "US"), class = "factor"), pair_no = c(1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L)), .Names = c("cc", "pair_no"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
```

Comment: Thanks nicola I think this works for me only that I need to have it in a matrix form to be able to make a heatmap afterwards. Can you modify the answer to give the results as a matrix?

Comment: as.matrix(table(data.frame(cc1=df$cc[c(T,F)],cc2=df$cc[c(F,T)])))

Comment: A `table` with two dimensions *is* a matrix. Anyway, you can call `as.matrix` as @DiegoAgher suggested, but you don't need to.